# Auto loop NanoTween animations in HTML5 banner ad

Tags: javascript, html, tween, banner-ads

I am hoping to auto loop a HTML5 banner advertisement that I have. The animations are built using NanoTween. Here is the JS code:

```
var container  = getElement("id","container");

var items = {
c1: getElement("id", "copy_1"),
c2: getElement("id", "copy_2"),
c3: getElement("id", "copy_3"),
c4: getElement("id", "copy_4"),
c5: getElement("id", "copy_5"),
c6: getElement("id", "copy_6"),
button: getElement("id", "button"),
elipseOverlay: getElement("id", "elipseOverlay"),
elipseOverlay2: getElement("id", "elipseOverlay2"),
elipse: getElement("id", "elipse"),
elipse2: getElement("id", "elipse2"),
elipseContainer: getElement("id", "elipseContainer"),
bar: getElement("id", "bar"),
magnaclick: getElement("id", "magnaclick"),
shirt: getElement("id", "shirt")
};

function init() {
 setTimeout(function() {
    startAnimation();
}, 5);
};

//
function startAnimation() {
container.style.visibility = "visible";

var delay = 0;
var quickerSpeed = 0.3;
var mediumSpeed = 1.7;
var quickSpeed = 0.5;

var easeInQuad = "cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.985, 0.340, 0.985)";
var easeOutQuad = "cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940)";
var linear = 'linear';
var pause = 3.6;
var loop = 0;
var loops = 1;

var magnaClickFps = 15;
var shirtFps = 10;
var magnaClickFrames = 5;
var shirtFrames = 5;


var magnaclick = function() {
    for (var i=1; i<=magnaClickFrames; i++) {
        (function(idx){
            setTimeout(function(){
                items.magnaclick.className = 'sprite2 magnaclick-'+idx;
            },(idx-1)*(1000/magnaClickFps));
        })(i);
    }
};

var shirt = function() {
    for (var i=2; i<=shirtFrames; i++) {
        (function(idx){
            setTimeout(function(){
                items.shirt.style = '';
                items.shirt.className = 'sprite2 shirt-'+idx;
            },(idx-1)*(1000/shirtFps));
        })(i);
    }
};

var animate = function() {

    loop++;

    // reset
    NanoTween.to(items.c1, 0, { opacity: 0, scale:0.2, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    NanoTween.to(items.c2, 0, { opacity: 0, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    NanoTween.to(items.c3, 0, { opacity: 0, scale:0.2, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    NanoTween.to(items.c4, 0, { opacity: 0, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    NanoTween.to(items.c5, 0, { transform: 'translate3d(-150px, 0px, 0px)', opacity: 0, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    NanoTween.to(items.c6, 0, { transform: 'translate3d(150px, 0px, 0px)', opacity: 0, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    NanoTween.to(items.button, 0, { opacity: 1, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});

    // initial delay
    delay += 0.2;

    // circle 1st half
    setTimeout(function(){
        items.elipseOverlay2.className += ' in';
        items.elipse2.className += ' in';
    },delay*1000);

    // circle second half
    setTimeout(function(){
        items.elipseOverlay.className += ' in';
        items.elipse.className += ' in';
    },(delay+=.2)*1000);

    // cicrcle bar
    setTimeout(function(){
        items.bar.className += ' in';
    },(delay+=.2)*1000);

    delay += quickerSpeed;

    // no more zoom in
    NanoTween.to(items.c1, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 1, scale: 1,  ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    //NanoTween.to(items.c1, quickSpeed, { transform: 'translate(0px, -10px)', ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    delay += 2*quickerSpeed;

    // fussing with buttons fade in
    NanoTween.to(items.c2, quickSpeed, { opacity: 1, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    //NanoTween.to(items.c2, quickSpeed, { transform: 'translate(0px, -10px)', ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});

    // pause after frame 1
    delay += quickSpeed + 1.2;

    // frame 1 fade out
    NanoTween.to(items.elipseContainer, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
    NanoTween.to(items.c1, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
    NanoTween.to(items.c2, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
    NanoTween.to(items.bar, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
    NanoTween.to(items.button, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
    delay += quickerSpeed;

    // magnaclick animation
    //setTimeout(magnaclick, delay*1000);
    //delay += ((1000/magnaClickFps)*magnaClickFrames/1000);

    //magnaclick last farme static
    items.magnaclick.className = 'sprite2 magnaclick-5';
    NanoTween.to(items.magnaclick, 1, { opacity: 1, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay - 0.5});
    NanoTween.to(items.magnaclick, quickSpeed, { transform: 'translate(0px, 10px)', ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay - 0.5});

    // new zoom in
    NanoTween.to(items.c3, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 1, scale: 1, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    //NanoTween.to(items.c3, quickSpeed, { transform: 'translate(0px, -10px)', ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    delay += quickerSpeed + 0.2; // + pause

    // magnetic buttons fade in
    NanoTween.to(items.c4, quickSpeed, { opacity: 1, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
    //NanoTween.to(items.c4, quickSpeed, { transform: 'translate(0px, -10px)', ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});

    // pause
    delay += quickSpeed + 0.5;

    // copy fades out
    NanoTween.to(items.c3, mediumSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
    NanoTween.to(items.c4, mediumSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
    // shirt fades in
    NanoTween.to(items.shirt, mediumSpeed, { opacity: 1, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});

    delay += quickSpeed;
    setTimeout(shirt, delay*1000);

    delay += ((1000/shirtFps)*shirtFrames/1000);
    NanoTween.to(items.c5, quickerSpeed, { transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)', opacity: 1, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
    delay += quickSpeed;
    NanoTween.to(items.c6, quickerSpeed, { transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)', opacity: 2, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});



    //
    //if (loop<loops) {
    //    delay += +quickerSpeed + pause;
    //    NanoTween.to(items.i3, quickerSpeed, { transform: 'translate3d(-150px, 0px, 0px)', opacity:0, ease: easeOutQuad, delay: delay });
    //    NanoTween.to(items.c3, quickerSpeed, { transform: 'translate3d(150px, 0px, 0px)', opacity:0, ease: easeOutQuad, delay: delay });
    //
    //    setTimeout(animate, quickerSpeed*1000);
    //}
};

animate();

}

function getElement(element, id) {
var mc;
switch(element){
    case "id":
        mc = document.getElementById(id);
        break;

    case "class":
        mc = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
        break;
}

return mc;
}


window.onload = function(){
init();
};
```

Is there code that I can add to automatically loop this animation after a brief pause on the last frame? Please let me know if this is possible. Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding the following after the last NanoTween call. The cycle will pause for 3.6 seconds (`var pause = 3.6;`) before restarting.

```
// the last Tween ran for this duration, so we need to include to get the total duration
delay += quickerSpeed; 

setTimeout(function() {
    delay = 0; // reset animation total duration counter
    animate(); // begin again
}, (delay + pause) * 1000); // Convert delay & pause to milliseconds & restart once time has elapsed
```

Here's the full code incorporating the above changes:

```
var container  = getElement("id","container");

var items = {
    c1: getElement("id", "copy_1"),
    c2: getElement("id", "copy_2"),
    c3: getElement("id", "copy_3"),
    c4: getElement("id", "copy_4"),
    c5: getElement("id", "copy_5"),
    c6: getElement("id", "copy_6"),
    button: getElement("id", "button"),
    elipseOverlay: getElement("id", "elipseOverlay"),
    elipseOverlay2: getElement("id", "elipseOverlay2"),
    elipse: getElement("id", "elipse"),
    elipse2: getElement("id", "elipse2"),
    elipseContainer: getElement("id", "elipseContainer"),
    bar: getElement("id", "bar"),
    magnaclick: getElement("id", "magnaclick"),
    shirt: getElement("id", "shirt")
};

function init() {
     setTimeout(function() {
        startAnimation();
    }, 5);
};

//
function startAnimation() {
    container.style.visibility = "visible";

    var delay = 0;
    var quickerSpeed = 0.3;
    var mediumSpeed = 1.7;
    var quickSpeed = 0.5;

    var easeInQuad = "cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.985, 0.340, 0.985)";
    var easeOutQuad = "cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940)";
    var linear = 'linear';
    var pause = 3.6;
    var loop = 0;
    var loops = 5;

    var magnaClickFps = 15;
    var shirtFps = 10;
    var magnaClickFrames = 5;
    var shirtFrames = 5;


    var magnaclick = function() {
        for (var i=1; i<=magnaClickFrames; i++) {
            (function(idx){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    items.magnaclick.className = 'sprite2 magnaclick-'+idx;
                },(idx-1)*(1000/magnaClickFps));
            })(i);
        }
    };

    var shirt = function() {
        for (var i=2; i<=shirtFrames; i++) {
            (function(idx){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    items.shirt.style = '';
                    items.shirt.className = 'sprite2 shirt-'+idx;
                },(idx-1)*(1000/shirtFps));
            })(i);
        }
    };

    var animate = function() {

        loop++;

        // reset
        NanoTween.to(items.c1, 0, { opacity: 0, scale:0.2, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
        NanoTween.to(items.c2, 0, { opacity: 0, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
        NanoTween.to(items.c3, 0, { opacity: 0, scale:0.2, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
        NanoTween.to(items.c4, 0, { opacity: 0, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
        NanoTween.to(items.c5, 0, { transform: 'translate3d(-150px, 0px, 0px)', opacity: 0, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
        NanoTween.to(items.c6, 0, { transform: 'translate3d(150px, 0px, 0px)', opacity: 0, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
        NanoTween.to(items.button, 0, { opacity: 1, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});

        // initial delay
        delay += 0.2;

        // circle 1st half
        setTimeout(function(){
            items.elipseOverlay2.className += ' in';
            items.elipse2.className += ' in';
        },delay*1000);

        // circle second half
        setTimeout(function(){
            items.elipseOverlay.className += ' in';
            items.elipse.className += ' in';
        },(delay+=.2)*1000);

        // cicrcle bar
        setTimeout(function(){
            items.bar.className += ' in';
        },(delay+=.2)*1000);

        delay += quickerSpeed;

        // no more zoom in
        NanoTween.to(items.c1, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 1, scale: 1,  ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
        //NanoTween.to(items.c1, quickSpeed, { transform: 'translate(0px, -10px)', ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
        delay += 2*quickerSpeed;

        // fussing with buttons fade in
        NanoTween.to(items.c2, quickSpeed, { opacity: 1, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
        //NanoTween.to(items.c2, quickSpeed, { transform: 'translate(0px, -10px)', ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});

        // pause after frame 1
        delay += quickSpeed + 1.2;

        // frame 1 fade out
        NanoTween.to(items.elipseContainer, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
        NanoTween.to(items.c1, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
        NanoTween.to(items.c2, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
        NanoTween.to(items.bar, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
        NanoTween.to(items.button, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
        delay += quickerSpeed;

        // magnaclick animation
        //setTimeout(magnaclick, delay*1000);
        //delay += ((1000/magnaClickFps)*magnaClickFrames/1000);

            //magnaclick last frame static
            items.magnaclick.className = 'sprite2 magnaclick-5';
            NanoTween.to(items.magnaclick, 1, { opacity: 1, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay - 0.5});
            NanoTween.to(items.magnaclick, quickSpeed, { transform: 'translate(0px, 10px)', ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay - 0.5});

        // new zoom in
        NanoTween.to(items.c3, quickerSpeed, { opacity: 1, scale: 1, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
        //NanoTween.to(items.c3, quickSpeed, { transform: 'translate(0px, -10px)', ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
        delay += quickerSpeed + 0.2; // + pause

        // magnetic buttons fade in
        NanoTween.to(items.c4, quickSpeed, { opacity: 1, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});
            //NanoTween.to(items.c4, quickSpeed, { transform: 'translate(0px, -10px)', ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});

        // pause
        delay += quickSpeed + 0.5;

        // copy fades out
        NanoTween.to(items.c3, mediumSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
        NanoTween.to(items.c4, mediumSpeed, { opacity: 0, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
        // shirt fades in
        NanoTween.to(items.shirt, mediumSpeed, { opacity: 1, ease:easeInQuad, delay: delay});

        delay += quickSpeed;
        setTimeout(shirt, delay*1000);

        delay += ((1000/shirtFps)*shirtFrames/1000);
        NanoTween.to(items.c5, quickerSpeed, { transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)', opacity: 1, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
        delay += quickSpeed;
        NanoTween.to(items.c6, quickerSpeed, { transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)', opacity: 2, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay})

        // the last Tween ran for this duration, so we need to include to get the total duration
        delay += quickerSpeed; 

        setTimeout(function() {
            delay = 0; 
            animate();
        }, (delay + pause) * 1000); // delay & pause are in seconds

        //
        //if (loop<loops) {
        //    delay += +quickerSpeed + pause;
        //    NanoTween.to(items.i3, quickerSpeed, { transform: 'translate3d(-150px, 0px, 0px)', opacity:0, ease: easeOutQuad, delay: delay });
        //    NanoTween.to(items.c3, quickerSpeed, { transform: 'translate3d(150px, 0px, 0px)', opacity:0, ease: easeOutQuad, delay: delay });
        //
        //    setTimeout(animate, quickerSpeed*1000);
        //}
    };

    animate();
}

function getElement(element, id) {
    var mc;
    switch(element){
        case "id":
            mc = document.getElementById(id);
            break;

        case "class":
            mc = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
            break;
    }

    return mc;
}


window.onload = function(){
    init();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
var animate = function() {
```

To this:

```
function animate() {
```

And add one more call to animate() here:

```
NanoTween.to(items.c6, quickerSpeed, { transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)', opacity: 2, ease:easeOutQuad, delay: delay});
animate()
```

Not sure if  there will be any problems with Nano tween but this will at least loop your function call. You can't use the var `animate = function() {` syntax because then the animate variable is not accessible inside the function.

Comment: This will probably not work because of the timeouts. Callbacks should be implemented.